How to stop reload after download button has been used?
I use downloadLink() within R Shiny. If this was used, i.e. clicked on, the whole app, or in my case the Quarto Dashboard, reloads. So the users end up back on the start page, which is not good for the user experience.
How can I avoid the reloading triggered by the click/use of the button?
This is my code:
downloadLink("downloadBMGrafik", "Download Benchmark-Grafik")
downloadLink("downloadTabelle", "Download Tabelle")
downloadLink("downloadJVGrafik", "Download Jahresvergleich-Grafik")

[...]
#| context: server
[...]
output$downloadBMGrafik <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("Benchmark-Grafik_", name_skala_item(),"_", jahresauswahl(), ".png")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    grafikGruppe1 <- grafik_generieren(jahresauswahl(), auswahl_skala_item(), kh_gruppe_1, titel())
    grafikGruppe2 <- grafik_generieren(jahresauswahl(), auswahl_skala_item(), kh_gruppe_2, titel())
    kombinierteGrafik <- grafikGruppe1 + grafikGruppe2
    ggsave(file, plot=kombinierteGrafik, width = 20, height = 10)
  }
)

output$downloadTabelle <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("Tabelle_", name_skala_item(),"_", jahresauswahl(), ".png")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    tabelle <- tabelle_generieren(jahresauswahl(), auswahl_skala_item())
    tempFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
    gt::gtsave(tabelle, tempFile)
    webshot::webshot(tempFile, file, delay = 0.2, selector = "body", vwidth = 1200, vheight = 800)
  }
)

output$downloadJVGrafik <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("Jahresvergleich-Grafik_", name_skala_item(),"_", jahresauswahl(), ".png")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    grafik <- jahresvergleich_generieren(auswahl_skala_item(), jahre, titel())
    ggsave(file, plot=grafik, width=20, height=10)
  }
)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
